# Export Function From Test file and use it in component file?

Tags: node.js, angular, testcase

I am new in Angular and NodeJS UTs. I have a function in test file and I have exported that function to use it in another file but once I call it from another file then I am receiving an error of describe block. Here is my code:

`abc.controller.ts`

```
export function mockGetAppByName(exists: boolean, error?: boolean) {
// some execution
}
```

`mock.app.ts`

```
    import { mockGetAppByName} from '../../test/api/abc/abc.controller.test';

    //Called function below in some other function
    mockGetAppByName(true);
```

When I run command `npm start` It throws below error. If I does not export it then it works fine...When I export and import this function in another file then also I am not receiving any error...BUT...once I call that function in my code then it throws an error. It does not allow my server to start and it keep throwing error.

`ERROR`

> C:\Ambuj Khanna\Project\STA_Console\STAConsole\server\tmp\test\api\action\action.controller.test.js:194
>   describe('ActionController', () => { 
>   ^
>
> ReferenceError: describe is not defined
>       at Object. (C:\Ambuj 
>   Khanna\Project\project\server\tmp\test\api\action\abc.controller.test.js:194:1)
>   ←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)←[39m
>       at Object. (C:\Ambuj 
>   Khanna\Project\project\server\tmp\src\mock\mock.application.js:10:34)
>   ←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)←[39m 
>       at Object. (C:\Ambuj
>   Khanna\Project\STA_Console\STAConsole\server\tmp\src\mock\index.js:5:28)
>   ←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)←[39m
>   ←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)←[39m
>      at Object. (C:\Ambuj Khanna\Project\STA_Console\STAConsole\server\tmp\src\app.js:7:14)

Comment: It is how Angular builds apps, file code should be valid. First of all you should not import any methods from test to actual code, it should be done vice versa. Did you try to do so?

Comment: Hi @KaterinaPavlenko Yes i tried same and it was working for me but I actually wanted to know the reason why this kind of error comes while we import anything from test file.